# UIBarButtonItem set color for states

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, uicolor

Trying to set color for a `UIBarButtonItem`. The problem is that I can't `setTitleTextAttributes` for both `UIControlStateDisabled` and `UIControlStateNormal` with two different `NSDictionaries`.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
NSDictionary *enabled = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                  [UIColor purpleColor],NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                                  [UIFont fontWithName:@"Playball" size:20], NSFontAttributeName,
                                                  nil];



NSDictionary *disabled = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                   [UIColor yellowColor],NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                                   [UIFont fontWithName:@"Playball" size:20], NSFontAttributeName,
                                                   nil];

[[self toolBarItem] setTitleTextAttributes:disabled forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
[[self toolBarItem] setTitleTextAttributes:enabled forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[[self toolBarItem] setEnabled:NO];
```

For some reason the `toolBarItem` is purple, when it should be yellow, since `setEnable:NO`, thus disabled.

Comment: in which method of your view controller is this code being called?

Comment: viewDidLoad. But later I'll put them in the AppDelegate, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions; [UIBarButtonItem appearance]...